# Substring of text variable

Tags: ruby

I have a string in the variable `text`. If I do `text[0 .. 29]` I get the first 30 characters. What if I want the last part of string which I don't know the length?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `test[-30..-1]` Doc: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D

Answer (score 1):

If you have activesupport/rails, you can also pass the number of characters to `last`.

```
text.last(30)
```

Comment: This solution requires activesupport (rails). Thus the downvotes I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Use negative indices:

```
a = "qwertyuiop"
a[-3..-1]
"iop"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `test[30..-1]`, which makes more sense to me than `test[-30,-1]`